# Row Count on DataTable Does Not Refresh

Tags: javascript, yui

I have an Alloy UI `DataTable` created when a search form is submitted - this table displays x amount of records as well as the number of records returned

```
 var dataTable = new Y.DataTable({
     columns: columns,
     footerView:   Y.FooterView, 
     scrollable: 'y',
     height: '95%',
     footerConfig: {
         fixed:   true,
         heading: {
             colspan:    5,
             content:    "Number of Records : {row_count}" //returns number of rows
         }
 });
```

On Submit:

```
node.on( //search button
'click',
//make request
success: function(e) {
    //do some stuff
    dataTable.set('data', responseText); //adds data to DataTable
    //function to refresh {row_count}?
}
```

When the search form is resubmitted, the DataTable is reloaded, however {row_count} does not get refreshed to match records returned. Is there a simple way to reload this count after each request?

Answer (score 0):

You can count the rows like this and try refresh your {row_count} with Y.one('#??').set('value',xyz) on your own

```
node.on( //search button
'click',
//make request
success: function(e) {

    var row_count = 0;

    //do some stuff
    dataTable.set('data', responseText); //adds data to DataTable
    //function to refresh {row_count}?
    row_count = dataTable.get('data').size();
    // something like this --> Y.one('#??').set('value',row_count);


}
```